# Isomorphic (Universal) web application and SEO

Tags: seo, search-engines, react-js

I am developing an isomorphic web application using React (SSR). However, I need to render some of my components on the client side. Therefore, the things that a Google bot sees may be different from the things that users see. The components that I talk about are not important for my SEO concerns and I try to render all SEO related content on the server. Is this difference important for Google and may it have some impacts on my website ranking?